# How to integrate radial distribution function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration

[image]

i have this equation in my lecture notes, where $g(r)$ is the radial distribution function, $n(r)$ is the average number of particles within r to r + dr, and professor said this g(r) can be integrated to 1. So i try in so many many ways to integrate it, but also failed. i emailed Professor but he don't respond to my email, students not interested to my question and say it just integrate to 1, you have to believe it is 1. So can anyone help me how to integrate this equation to 1, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

What a totally weird and deranged way to define
$$
N(R)/V=  \int_0^R n(r)dr=  4\pi \int_0^R g(r) r^2 dr
$$
where, presumably,  $N(\infty)/V$ is some sort of  density. What doe the "the" in the "the radial density function" mean. The radial density of what?

Note that the equation must be intended  as a   *definition* of $g(r)$, so there is nothing to prove.